# store dynamic data in variable python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

i my code i have created one function for generate pdf. it can be called more then 2 times in code but at 1st time it can be fetch my data but after second time they give me none value. how can i store my data in list.
i am using list.append but when method call 2nd time then it can be give me null value [that is stored default in database]
my code is:-

```
def GeneratePdf(request, type):
    # data for testing
    # global data
    template = get_template("employeereport/appointment.html")
    # real data
    empid = request.GET.get('empid')
    Date = request.GET.get('date')

    a = []

    a.append(Date)

    print(a)

    output:- 
    ['07/13/2020']
    [None]



    expected output-
    ['07/13/2020',None]
```

Comment: You need to provide some sort of reproducible example. Your code *doesn't actually output anything* since you simply define a function and call it. Please be precise and describe exactly what you are doing. It is totally unclear to me *what you expect*

Comment: The output doesn't match the code; the function is printing out three variables (two sets and a list) while the output shows four items (all lists). The function also seems to be doing two unrelated things (first based on `request`, second getting input from the local user). Can you check and update the question, please?

Comment: @sabik just check it i am change my code

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga just check it i update my code

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i have one function it can be called every time but my data is not append with list [show in expected output] it can be create new list [in output]. what can i do for that?

Comment: The variable `a` is local; each time the function exits, local variables are destroyed (immediately or eventually). To keep the results of the function, you should (ideally) return them; if necessary, you can add them to some list that you either pass in, or declare as global, but if you can return the value and handle it in the caller, that's much better.

Comment: You create a new list every time, `a = []` Your function does nothing else with that list except printing it. It ceases to exist after the function exists. If you want to accumulate values in a list, you could use a global list (this is almost always bad design), you could use a class with an instance variable that is a list, or you could pass in a list to the function which the function modifies (also generally not a great design, although better than globals). Alternatively, your function can just return `Date` and it would be up to the caller to create the list.

Answer (score 0):

declare the list before using it

```
a = []
def function():
    a.append(1)
function()
function()
print(a)
```